# Client, Evaluating Clients, and Attracting Clients?

Tags: discussion, tags

Now that our first self-evaluation is under our belt, I started going through the list of questions from the self-eval to try and improve them a bit.

I discovered some tags that we should review.

**[client](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client)**

Freelancers have clients. I don't think it's possible to be a freelancer and not have clients; therefore, I'm not sure that such a tag really tells us much about the contents of the question. I'm planning to put a blacklist request in for this tag, but first, we as a community should go through and suggest edits to these questions to improve them, as well as doing any necessary retagging to make it easier for folks to find the questions.

**[evaluating-clients](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluating-clients)**

This seems like a better tag. It's more specific. I can look at the tag and know the question has something to do with *evaluating* clients. This narrows things down enough to be useful.

[attracting-clients](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attracting-clients)

Similar to evaluating clients, this tag also narrows things down. But how is it different from the [marketing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) tag?

So, I ask you Freelancing SE community, what shall we do with these tags?

Answer (score 1):

Agree that [clients](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clients) is a bit woolly, but it probably has a role if restricted to client relationship issues?

Perhaps [clients](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clients) and maybe even [evaluating-clients](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluating-clients) should be merged as [managing-clients](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/managing-clients)?

I definitely agree that [attracting-clients](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attracting-clients) is (IMHO) a synonym for [marketing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) - perhaps renamed as [sales-and-marketing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sales-and-marketing) to cover both bases?

Comment: (1) Merging clients with evaluating clients still seems kind of broad. I'm not entirely sure combining all of them at this time would be best, at least not without another 3-6 months of Q&A under our belts on Freelancing SE.  (2) Attracting clients, marketing, and sales and marketing are all things that I could see being merged, especially attracting clients and marketing. I could see room for doubt on sales... maybe.